# How to get a detailed data of a specific list view item

Tags: java, android

hi 
  i have build a rss by watching ibm tutorial . In this i get a list view of rss feeds.
i have a class showdescription in which i am taking the description of the specific list view item.

But it does not show the descriton on item click.

here is my code for onclicklistener

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
 {
     Log.i(tag,"item clicked! [" + feed.getItem(position).getTitle() + "]");

     Intent itemintent = new Intent(this,ShowDescription.class);

     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("title", feed.getItem(position).getTitle());
     b.putString("description", feed.getItem(position).getDescription());
     b.putString("link", feed.getItem(position).getLink());
     b.putString("pubdate", feed.getItem(position).getPubDate());

     itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);

     startSubActivity(itemintent,0);
 }
```

and this code shows error in startSubActivity and ask to implement its method which is

```
private void startSubActivity(Intent itemintent, int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
```

but it does not shows the details of particular item